# Dollar sign char issue on WAMP

Tags: php, wamp

I have an irritating issue on WAMP server where the dollar sign strips the following two characters.

```
$dollar_sign = '$';
var_dump($dollar_sign); // Returns string '$' (length=1)
echo $dollar_sign .'1234'; // Displays 34

echo '$' . number_format(1234, 0, '', ''); // Displays 34
echo '$1234'; // Displays 34
echo ord('$'); // Returns 36
```

Using single quotes, not double.

Debug from the real code:

```
var_dump(bin2hex(self::$currencies[$code]['prefix'])); // Returns 5c24
```

I tried different charsets Windows-1252, ISO-8859-1 and UTF-8 but it does not seem to be a charset problem.

It works on any LAMP server (Linux) but not Windows.

Note: I'm not looking for a HTML entity workaround.

Edit: The following works, but I would like to know why. It's like single quotes have an eval() behavior in my WAMP installation.

```
echo str_replace('$', '\$', $dollar_sign) . '1234'; // Displays $1234
echo chr(36) . '1234'; // Displays $1234
```

Edit 2: Solved, see the answer where a template handler was the cause.

Comment: This code works fine for me on WAMP. You have an issue on your computer somewhere but outside of basic WAMP. Do you have any special php settings configured?

Comment: Works as expected from command line and using `php -S` on Windows 7, PHP 5.5.5.

Comment: Not reproducible. `echo '$1234';` displays `$1234` for everyone else. Show your complete code, or elaborate on your setup.

Comment: Did you try uninstalling it and re-installing the most current version?

Comment: Jessica: Using the latest WAMP already. I'm not suprised it cannot be reproduced. I've never seen this behavior in 7 years of PHP coding.

Comment: It's probably not the PHP version, it's more likely the incorrect use of a function. Always happens to me! :D @tim, could you post the whole code that this issue is recording, functions and all?

Comment: Is this your entire code? How are you evaluating / observing the output of this script (HTML document / written to text file / email body / etc)?

Comment: MMcdonald. It's a framework of different files and classes. I will try debugging the content of the $dollar_sign variable.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this may not be a proper answer.
However, I suspect this is not a PHP problem, it looks like your testing browser issues.

To prove it, would you please run:

```
$dollar_sign = '$';
echo base64_encode($dollar_sign .'1234');
```

Then, would you please paste the result here?

Answer (score 0):

Here we go, the framework has a template system where snippets are preg_replaced.

This gave the content hickups before returning it to the browser.

```
$html = preg_replace($snippet_name, $snippet_content, $html, -1, $replacements);
```

changed to

```
$html = preg_replace($snippet_name, str_replace('$', '\$', $snippet_content), $html, -1, $replacements);
```

This explains why it was not reproducable for y'all. I could never have guessed this was the cause. But it's pretty logic after discovering it.